# Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame `df`:

```
    A    B
a   2    2 
b   3    1
c   1    3
```

I want to create a new column based on the following criteria:

if row `A == B: 0`

if row`A > B: 1`

if row `A < B: -1`

so given the above table, it should be:

```
    A    B    C
a   2    2    0
b   3    1    1
c   1    3   -1
```

For typical `if else` cases I do `np.where(df.A > df.B, 1, -1)`, does pandas provide a special syntax for solving my problem with one step (without the necessity of creating 3 new columns and then combining the result)?

Comment: @DSM has answered this question but I meant something like `df['C']=df.apply(myFunc(row), axis=1)` where myFunc does what you want, this does not involve creating '3 columns'

Comment: Since pandas 2.2.0, you can use `case_when` (a syntax useful in SQL in the context in the OP). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73619829/19123103) for a demo.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

To formalize some of the approaches laid out above:

Create a function that operates on the rows of your dataframe like so:

```
def f(row):
    if row['A'] == row['B']:
        val = 0
    elif row['A'] > row['B']:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = -1
    return val
```

Then apply it to your dataframe passing in the `axis=1` option:

```
In [1]: df['C'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B  C
a  2  2  0
b  3  1  1
c  1  3 -1
```

Of course, this is not vectorized so performance may not be as good when scaled to a large number of records.  Still, I think it is much more readable. Especially coming from a SAS background.

**Edit**

Here is the vectorized version

```
df['C'] = np.where(
    df['A'] == df['B'], 0, np.where(
    df['A'] >  df['B'], 1, -1))
```

Comment: What if I want to pass another parameter along with row in the function? If I do, it says row not defined..

Comment: You have to use the `args` parameter of the `.apply` function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: I'm an old SAS user learning Python, and there's definitely a learning curve! :-) For example, the above code could be written in SAS as: `data df; set df; if A=B then C=0; else if A>B then C=1; else C=-1; run;` Very elegant and simple.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I could not understand why `axis=1` is required. Without passing `axis=1` the row had only 1st column.

Comment: @Zelazny7 could you please give a vectorized version?

Comment: For the unvectorized, your function contains arguments - and so it would be:
df['c'] = df(lambda row: f(row), axis=1)

Answer (score 92):

```
df.loc[df['A'] == df['B'], 'C'] = 0
df.loc[df['A'] > df['B'], 'C'] = 1
df.loc[df['A'] < df['B'], 'C'] = -1
```

Easy to solve using indexing. The first line of code reads like so, if column `A` is equal to column `B` then create and set column `C` equal to 0.

Answer (score 18):

For this particular relationship, you could use `np.sign`:

```
>>> df["C"] = np.sign(df.A - df.B)
>>> df
   A  B  C
a  2  2  0
b  3  1  1
c  1  3 -1
```

Answer (score 12):

When you have multiple `if`
conditions, [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is the way to go:

```
In [4102]: import numpy as np
In [4098]: conditions = [df.A.eq(df.B), df.A.gt(df.B), df.A.lt(df.B)]
In [4096]: choices = [0, 1, -1]

In [4100]: df['C'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

In [4101]: df
Out[4101]: 
   A  B  C
a  2  2  0
b  3  1  1
c  1  3 -1
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Lets say above one is your original dataframe and you want to add a new column 'old'

**If age greater than 50 then we consider as older=yes otherwise False**

step 1: Get the indexes of rows whose age greater than 50 
    `row_indexes=df[df['age']>=50].index`  
step 2:
 Using .loc we can assign a new value to column 
    `df.loc[row_indexes,'elderly']="yes"`

**same for age below less than 50** 
    `row_indexes=df[df['age']<50].index` 
    `df[row_indexes,'elderly']="no"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the method `mask`:

```
df['C'] = np.nan
df['C'] = df['C'].mask(df.A == df.B, 0).mask(df.A > df.B, 1).mask(df.A < df.B, -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

a **one liner** solution with `list comprehension` and `zip()` is also

```
df.loc[:,'C']= [0 if d1==d2 else 1 if d1>d2 else -1 for d1,d2 in zip(df.A,df.B)]
```

which returns the desired output

Answer (score 1):

This is a one line of code that achieves the desired result.
This line of code assigns a new column 'C' to the DataFrame 'df'. The new column 'C' will have a value of 0 if the values in columns 'A' and 'B' are equal, a value of 1 if the value in column 'A' is greater than the value in column 'B', and a value of -1 if the value in column 'A' is less than the value in column 'B'.

To achieve this, the apply function is used on the DataFrame 'df'. The apply function applies a function along a given axis of the DataFrame. In this case, the axis is set to 1, which means the function will be applied to each row in the DataFrame.

The function being applied is a lambda function that takes a row as input. It checks the values in columns 'A' and 'B' of the current row and returns the appropriate value (0, 1, or -1) for the new column 'C'.

After running this line of code, the DataFrame 'df' will have an additional column 'C' with the calculated values based on the comparison of columns 'A' and 'B'.

```
import pandas as pd
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: 0 if row['A'] == row['B'] else 1 if row['A'] > row['B'] else -1, axis=1)
```