# Add a column to pandas DataFrame based on the values of two other columns using groupby ( )

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a very large data file which can be modelled with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

x = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': np.repeat(['csv_1', 'csv_2'], 32),
                  'side': np.tile(np.repeat(['n', 'f'], 16),2),
                  'ten_13':np.tile(np.repeat(['10', '13'], 8),4),
                  'rand_data': np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=64)})

x = x.set_index(['file_name', 'side', 'ten_13'])
x.head()
```

I need your help to add a column called `web_col` **using pandas' groupby( ) method** to the above DataFrame `x`.

The `web_col` column depends on the combination of values in columns `side`, `ten_13` and has one of four possible sequence values:

- 1:8   if the value of 'side' = 'n' and 'ten_13' = '10'
- 9:16  if the value of 'side' = 'n' and 'ten_13' = '13'
- 17:24 if the value of 'side' = 'f' and 'ten_13' = '10'
- 25:32 if the value of 'side' = 'f' and 'ten_13' = '13'

`file_name` contains various csv files; in the code below it has only two files. Each file has the same exact values of `side` and `ten_13`.

I created this `web_col` column using the numpy function `np.where()`, BUT I would like to use pandas' **groupby( )** instead. The `np.where()` code is below:

```
ten_13 = x.index.get_level_values('ten_13')
side   = x.index.get_level_values('side')

n_10 = ((ten_13 == '10') & (side == 'n')).reshape(-1,8)
n_13 = ((ten_13 == '13') & (side == 'n')).reshape(-1,8)
f_10 = ((ten_13 == '10') & (side == 'f')).reshape(-1,8)
f_13 = ((ten_13 == '13') & (side == 'f')).reshape(-1,8)

web_col = np.where(n_10, np.arange(1, 9, 1),
                   np.where(f_10, np.arange( 17, 25, 1),
                            np.where(n_13, np.arange(9, 17, 1),
                                     np.where(f_13, np.arange(25,33, 1), np.arange(1, 9, 1)))))
x['web_col'] = web_col.reshape(64,1)
x.head()
```

Comment: Why would you like to use groupby() specifically? groupby() doesn't feel like the right tool for this problem. groupby() is great for creating a grouping over which you will perform some aggregation, but that's not your goal. Perhaps an apply() is more appropriate?

Comment: Because I need to know more about groupby(), What tool do you think is appropriate for this problem?

Comment: Try [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition) for a good example

Answer (score -1):

You *could* use `pandas.apply()` for this, but considering that you have only 4 conditions, the following is probably more efficient.

```
x.loc[(x['side'] == 'n') & (x['ten_13'] == '10'), 'web_col'] = '1:8'
... for each condition
```

If you set the appropriate indexes, this will be even faster.

```
x.set_index(['side', 'ten_13'], inplace=True)
x.sortlevel(inplace=True)  # speeds up lookups
x.loc[('n', '10'), 'web_col'] = '1:8'
... for each condition
x.reset_index(inplace=True) # to restore original dataframe
```

Comment: thank you but the code you supplied does not work for the model data supplied. Additionally, I requested the solution to be with groupby ( ) method

Comment: There was a typo in the code - also, groupby is the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: Your code has the typo or mine? I understand, but I requested groupby(). Please notice that I provided a way to create the column using np.where( ). The purpose is for me to learn groupby ( )