# How can I change every value in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataframe including a column for months whose type is int64, and I want to change every value in the column to be the corresponding season of the year.

For example if x is any of 12, 1, or 2, change the value of x to `'winter'`, etc.

I have tried some for loops but no use. I think there is a one liner that can do this using `lambda x`.

I supposed that every month has only 1 season so for example winter is in months 12, 1, and 2, and so on.

For example (0, 1, and 2 are indices):

input:

```
0  1
1  3
2  6
```

output:

```
0  winter
1  spring
2  summer
```

My problem is with month 12 or else I could have used bins.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use numpy.where, numpy.select or df.loc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228596/pandas-case-when-default-in-pandas

Answer (score 1):

One fast and flexible way is to `map` a dict from current column values to new column values:

```
d = dict(zip(range(1,13), ["winter"]*2 + ["spring"]*3 + ["summer"]*3 + ["fall"]*3 + ["winter"]))    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(month=[3,4,6,1,5,6,2,4,5]))

df = df.month.map(d)
```

output:

```
0    spring
1    spring
2    summer
3    winter
4    spring
5    summer
6    winter
7    spring
8    spring
Name: month, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ok thank you for this nice solution

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) accepts a dict or a Series. (Values that are not found in the dict are converted to NaN.)

```
month2season = {1:'winter', 2:'winter', 3:'spring', ...}
s.map(month2season)  # s.apply(month2season) does the same thing
```

Comment: that;'s very helpful actually thanks

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have this dataframe (named `df`)

[image]

then u can easily write this function

```
def map_fn(x: int):
    if x in range(3, 6):
        return "spring"
    if x in range(6, 9):
        return "summer"
    if x in range(9, 12):
        return "autumn"
    return "winter"
```

and then apply it to your column like this

```
df.seasons.apply(map_fn)
```

to have this

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: Not a big deal, but the second two `if`s should be `elif`s.

Comment: `NaN`s will be mapped to `'winter'`, which is probably not what you want. You could add another check: `elif x in range(1, 3) or x == 12: return "winter"`, although `NaN`s will be mapped to `None`. hmm... I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using pandas replace and cut methods:

```
df['month']=df['month'].replace(12,0)

bin_edges = [-1,2,5,8,11]

bin_labels= ["winter",'spring','summer','fall']

df['month']=pd.cut(df['month'], bin_edges, labels=bin_labels)
```

Thanks all.