# Can't figure out why it's providing error message: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python

[image]

I have a dataset called 'combine' as screenshot above. ID, I_A, I_B, T_A, T_B are the original columns in the table. Now I want to generate the 'FLAG' column based on the condition below:

1. FLAG='Record is missing in file A.' when I_A = 'YES' and I_B is null
2. FLAG='Record is missing in file B.' when I_A = 'NO' or is null and I_B is not null
3. FLAG='time is different from file A and file B. Please check and update.' when I_A = 'DONE' and I_B is not null and T_A <> T_B

When satisfy multiple conditions, please combine these flags and separate by bar '|'.

I'm looking for some python code with concise style to realise this request. I've tried with multiple functions and combined the results, but it seems too redundant. Also, I've tried with below code and it seems not quite correct.

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame

ID = ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004']
I_A = ['YES', 'NO', '', 'DONE']
I_B = ['','1','2','3']
T_A = ['','','','10']
T_B = ['','','','11']

combine = {'ID': ID,
           'I_A': I_A,
           'I_B': I_B,
           'T_A': T_A,
           'T_B': T_B}

combine = DataFrame(combine)
print(combine)

# Create DER_FLAG

def flag(I_A, I_B, T_A, T_B):  
    if (I_A == 'NO' or I_A is None) and I_B is None:
        return 'Record is missing in file A.'
    if I_A == 'YES' and I_B is None:
        return 'Record is missing in file B.'
    if (I_A == 'DONE' and I_B is not None and T_A != T_B):
        return 'time is different from file A and file B. Please check and update.'

combine['FLAG'] = combine.apply(flag(combine['I_A'], combine['I_B'], combine['T_A'], combine['T_B']))
```

It seems the code can't work and I can't figure out the error in it.
The Error Message is: **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**
Can anybody help with this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: `I've tried with multiple functions and combine the results, but it seems too redundant.` Can you please post those attempts? You may already have achieved it / will help others understand what you meant by concise

Comment: Also, kindly elaborate what exactly do you mean by a dataset, and what you are using in Python.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've posted? Apart from the logic being slightly wrong, that's about as concise as you're likely to get I would think. Regarding the wrong logic, the first 2 `if` statements don't match your first 2 written conditions

Comment: Yes, I've mocked this code from the original one. A ValueError is appearing for this code. But it doesn't matter. Could you please help to fix this code?

Comment: The ValueError is appearing in the evaluation of `flag(combine['I_A'], combine['I_B'], combine['T_A'], combine['T_B'])`.  The first argument to apply should be a function, not the evaluation of a function.  Try: `combine['FLAG'] = combine.apply(lambda row:flag(row['I_A'],
                                     row['I_B'],
                                     row['T_A'], 
                                     row['T_B']), 
                                axis = 1)`

Comment: Thank you for editing -- this is a much better question now, voting to reopen.

Comment: `if (I_A == 'NO'` This is the problem.  `I_A` is a _column_ containing _many_ values.  It does not make sense to compare an _entire column_ to a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given by DarrylG in the comments covers the problem:

> The ValueError is appearing in the evaluation of `flag(combine['I_A'], combine['I_B'], combine['T_A'], combine['T_B'])`.
> The first argument to apply should be a function, not the evaluation of a function. Try:
>
> ```py
> combine['FLAG'] = combine.apply(
>    lambda row:flag(row['I_A'], row['I_B'], row['T_A'],  row['T_B']), axis = 1)
> ```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your function, and change how you call it:

```py
def flag(row):  
    if (row['I_A'] == 'NO' or row['I_A'] is None) and row['I_B'] is None:
        return 'Record is missing in file A.'
    if row['I_A'] == 'YES' and row['I_B'] is None:
        return 'Record is missing in file B.'
    if (row['I_A'] == 'DONE' and row['I_B'] is not None and row['T_A'] != row['T_B']):
        return 'time is different from file A and file B. Please check and update.'

combine['FLAG'] = combine.apply(flag, axis=1)
```

For a more comprehensive response to this type of problem, have a look at [this SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228596/pandas-case-when-default-in-pandas)