# create labels in a new data frame column based on partial string match of a different column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

First, I have looked at many SO threads on this and none seemed to work in make case. 
[Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition) seemed to be the closest to what I am trying to do.

In my df I have a column with product names. I am trying to create a function that looks for a partial string match in each row of that column and based on the match it will create a label for each row in a new df column. I wanted to use a function because there are about 5 or 6 patterns that I need to match.

I am using contains() function to look for partial product title match. This returns a bool which I then check with else/if in the function:

```
def label_sub_cat():
    if data['product'].str.contains('Proceedings', case=False) is True:
        return 'Proceedings'
    elif data['product'].str.contains('DVD', case=False) is True:
        return 'DVD'
    else:
        return 'Other'

data['product_sub_cat'] = data.apply(label_sub_cat(), axis=1)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'other'
```

Comment: My theory since you don't provide data: your function label_sub_cat() is defined over your dataframe, so when you do data.apply(label_sub_cat(), ...) you're effectively doing data.apply('Other' ...)  hence the error

Comment: @Yuca can you elaborate on ' defined over your dataframe' part?

Comment: @Yuca it returns 'other'. So it must be an issue within the function itself. I am at a loss as to why. I did verify that running each contains() portion of the code does return True/False values.

Comment: @user3088202 when you write `data.apply(label_sub_cat(), axis=1)` you are telling pandas to apply `label_sub_cat()`. Notice how you're calling it here? You need to pass the function *object* try: `data.apply(label_sub_cat, axis=1)` instead. Also, your function is not taking any input. It will return the same boolean values as it's not comparing anything.

Comment: @BrianJoseph this gives me TypeError: ('label_sub_cat() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: that's what I mean by *defined over the dataframe*. That function is just doing two comparisons, which evaluate to False and False, landing on the else condition that returns 'Other'

Answer (score 1):

function in df.apply() should apply to each row of df, not for entire df.

```
In [37]: df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['aProcedings', 'aDVD','vcd']})
In [38]: def label_sub_cat(row):
...:     if 'Procedings' in row['product']:
...:         return 'Proceedings'
...:     elif 'DVD' in row['product']:
...:         return 'DVD'
...:     else:
...:         return 'Other'
...:
...:

In [39]: df['product_sub_cat'] = df.apply(label_sub_cat, axis=1)

In [40]: df
Out[40]:
       product product_sub_cat
0  aProcedings     Proceedings
1         aDVD             DVD
2          vcd           Other
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your function

```
def label_sub_cat(row):
    if row.product.str.contains('Proceedings', case=False) is True:
        return 'Proceedings'
    elif row.product.str.contains('DVD', case=False) is True:
        return 'DVD'
    else:
        return 'Other'

data['product_sub_cat'] = data.apply(label_sub_cat, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. All I was missing was the row part.

Comment: yup, hopefully the explanations helped to understand what was going on :) (and marking as accepted answer would be nice too!)