# return True if partial match success between two column

Tags: python

I am looking for partial matches success. below is the code for the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10,'aaaaa','aaa'], ['nick', 15,'vvvvv','vv'], ['juli', 14,'sssssss','kk']] 
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','random','partial'])
df
```

Output:
I am expecting the output shown below

```
   Name  Age   random partial  Matches
0   tom   10    aaaaa     aaa  True
1  nick   15    vvvvv      vv  True
2  juli   14  sssssss      kk  False
```

Comment: name age  random partial matches
tom  10 aaaaa aa TRUE
nick 15 vvvvv vvv TRUE
juli 14 sssssss kk Flase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) in combination with a lambda function that checks whether the partial string is part of the other string by using `in`.

Then we can assign this to a new column in the dataframe:

```
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>data = [['tom', 10,'aaaaa','aaa'], ['nick', 15,'vvvvv','vv'], ['juli',14,'sssssss','kk']] 
>>>df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','random','partial'])

>>>df['matching'] = df.apply(lambda x : x.partial in x.random, axis=1)
>>>print(df)
   Name  Age   random partial  matching
0   tom   10    aaaaa     aaa      True
1  nick   15    vvvvv      vv      True
2  juli   14  sssssss      kk     False
```

One important thing to be aware of when using `df.apply` is the `axis` argument, as it here allows us to access all columns of a given row at once.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Matches'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['partial'] in row['random'], axis = 'columns')
df
```

gives

```
Name    Age random  partial Matches
0   tom 10  aaaaa   aaa True
1   nick    15  vvvvv   vv  True
2   juli    14  sssssss kk  False
```

Comment: Name    Age  random                         partial                       Matches
0   tom      10     JP b c Morgan               JP Morgan               True
1   nick      15     morgan ba stanley         Morgan stanley       True
How we can solve this problem?