# Create a new column with unique identifier for each group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create a new "identifier column" with unique values for each combination of values of two columns. For example, the same "identifier" should be used when **ID** and **phase** are the same (e.g. r1 and ph1 [but a new, unique value should be added to the column when r1 and ph2])

```
df
ID   phase   side   values
r1   ph1     l      12
r1   ph1     r      34
r1   ph2     l      93
s4   ph3     l      21
s3   ph2     l      88
s3   ph2     r      54
...
```

I would need a new column (idx) like so:

```
new_df
ID   phase   side   values    idx
r1   ph1     l      12        1
r1   ph1     r      34        1
r1   ph2     l      93        2
s4   ph3     l      21        3
s3   ph2     l      88        4
s3   ph2     r      54        4
...
```

I've tried applying code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition) but could no achieve a way to increment the values in idx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-ngroup) + 1, use `sort=False` to ensure groups are enumerated in the order they appear in the DataFrame:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'phase'], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

`df`:

```
   ID phase side  values  idx
0  r1   ph1    l      12    1
1  r1   ph1    r      34    1
2  r1   ph2    l      93    2
3  s4   ph3    l      21    3
4  s3   ph2    l      88    4
5  s3   ph2    r      54    4
```