# Create sequential unique id for each group

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, grouping, unique, window-functions

I'm trying to find an equivalent for the following snippet ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67873779/6347629)) to create unique id to every unique combination from two columns in PySpark.

Pandas approach:

```py
df['my_id'] = df.groupby(['foo', 'bar'], sort=False).ngroup() + 1
```

I tried the following, but it's creating more ids than required:

```py
df = df.withColumn("my_id", F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('foo', 'bar')))
```

Comment: could you try `dense_rank`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `row_number`, use [**`dense_rank`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank.html#pyspark.sql.functions.dense_rank):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('r1', 'ph1'),
     ('r1', 'ph1'),
     ('r1', 'ph2'),
     ('s4', 'ph3'),
     ('s3', 'ph2'),
     ('s3', 'ph2')],
    ['foo', 'bar'])

df = df.withColumn("my_id", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('foo', 'bar')))
df.show()
# +---+---+-----+
# |foo|bar|my_id|
# +---+---+-----+
# | r1|ph1|    1|
# | r1|ph1|    1|
# | r1|ph2|    2|
# | s3|ph2|    3|
# | s3|ph2|    3|
# | s4|ph3|    4|
# +---+---+-----+
```

Comment: Could you please add, why the row_number is not working good? thanks

Comment: `row_number` just blindly counts every row. It doesn't compare values in the current row with values in previous row.