# How to make a new column with different values using "AND" in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,containing values of name and verified columns, i want to see if the conditions meet and it generates a new column with different valuess based on the condition,
For eg:

| Name | Verified |
| --- | --- |
| Mary | Yes |
| Julie | No |
| Mary | No |

Expected data:

| Name | Verified | Identity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Yes | Bot |
| Julie | No | Bot |
| Mary | No | Human |

What i have done:
I require a field where condition is if name is Mary and verified is No then print Human else Bot,

`df['Identity']=df((df['name'] == 'Mary') & (df['Verified'] == 'No)),`
I am not sure how to print human or bot based on the condition, can anyone please help?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Once you correct the structure of your conditional statement, you could do something like map, or use numpy where

```
df['Identity'] = ((df['Name'].eq('Mary')) & (df['Verified'].eq('No'))).map({True:'Human',False:'Bot'})
```

Or using numpy `where`

```
import numpy as np
df['Identity'] = np.where((df['Name'].eq('Mary')) & (df['Verified'].eq('No')),'Human','Bot')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use masks, it's faster than apply and map methods:

```py
mask = (df['name'] == 'Mary') & (df['Verified'] == 'No')
df.loc[mask,'Identity'] = 'Human'
df.loc[~mask,'Identity'] = 'Bot'
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, and what proof do you have that it's faster than map?  Did you try timing it?

Comment: Yeah, there was a mistake, thanks. Regarding the timing, yes. I've timing it. loc its a vectorized method, while map its a iterative method.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the results of the timing

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df['Identity'] = "Bot"
df.loc[(df['Name'] == "Mary") & (df['Verified'] == "No"), 'Identity'] = "Human"
```

Similar to this q: [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to it using np.where

```
df['Identify']=np.where(df['Name'].eq('Mary') & df['Verified'].eq('No'), 'Human', 'Bot')
df
```

```
    Name    Verified    Identify
0   Mary    Yes         Bot
1   Julie   No          Bot
2   Mary    No          Human
```