# Creating a new column in a DataFrame based on multiple condition using values from another column in Python

Tags: python

I would like to create a new column base on conditions from the Spread column.
The logic is:

if Spread is <= 4 then New_column = 4

if Spread is >4 and <=8 then New_column = 8

if Spread is >8 and <=12 Then new New_column = 12

if Spread is >12 Then new New_column = 16 (16 is the cut off.)

I have tried using .where but I have not any luck.
I would like the final output to look like below

| Spread | New_Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 8 |
| 6 | 8 |
| 9 | 12 |
| 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 16 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702342/creating-a-new-column-based-on-if-elif-else-condition)

Comment: Not explaining how to do with multiple conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equal spacing of your conditions allows for:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Spread':[1,2,5,6,9,11,13,20]})
df['NewCol'] = df['Spread'].apply(lambda x: min( 4*(1+(x//4)), 16) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html#pandas-cut):

```py
df['New_Column_2'] = (pd.cut(df['Spread'], [0, 4, 8, 12, np.inf]).cat.codes + 1) * 4
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Spread  New_Column  New_Column_2
0       1           4             4
1       2           4             4
2       5           8             8
3       6           8             8
4       9          12            12
5      11          12            12
6      13          16            16
7      24          16            16
```

Comment: This partially worked. Only problem is I have in the spread column records > 16 and for those it looks like it's marked as 0 in the New_column. Would like for anything >16 To be marked as 16 in the new_column

Comment: Thanks this works. I also got this to work as well:    
df['New_Column_2'] = np.where(TW_df.Spread >16, 16, (pd.cut(TW_df['Spread_Ticks'], [0, 4, 8, 12, 16]).cat.codes + 1) * 4)

Comment: I just nested your original answer with np.where

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` and create a `function`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Spread': [1,2,5,6,9,11,13]
})

def my_func(x): # Your function with your conditions
    if x <= 4:
        return 4
    elif x > 4 and x <= 8:
        return 8
    elif x > 8 and x <= 12:
        return 12
    elif x > 12:
        return 16
    else:
        return np.nan # In case none of your criteria is met

df['New_Column'] = df['Spread'].apply(my_func)
```

`df` is now:

```
   Spread  New_Column
0       1           4
1       2           4
2       5           8
3       6           8
4       9          12
5      11          12
6      13          16
```

Comment: Thanks, This worked also. I attempted this but i got a syntax error. With your example I see what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah no problem. Just wanted to clarify that you were able to resolve the syntax error? If not, can you elaborate more on what the error was?

Comment: Yes, I was able to resolve. When I tried this method prior to your answer I was getting an error due to a typo. I'm good to go now. Thanks