# adding new columns based on existing unique column combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| fips | year | pollutant | nonattainment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72137 | 1992 | Sulfur Dioxide (1971) |  |
| 72137 | 1992 | PM-2.5 (1997) | P |
| 72137 | 1992 | 8-Hour Ozone (2015) | W |
| 72137 | 1992 | 'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)' |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | Sulfur Dioxide (1971) |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | PM-2.5 (1997) |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | 8-Hour Ozone (2015) | W |
| 72137 | 1993 | 'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)' |  |

FYI:

- The `nonattainment` column has the value `P` or `W`
- The `pollutant` contains value within this list `['PM-2.5 (1997)', 'PM-2.5 (2006)', 'PM-10 (1987)', 'PM-2.5 (2012)']`.

**Task:**

I now want to add a new column called `nonattainment_pm`, which should contain the value `1`; if for any unique fips-year combination,

**Expected output:**

i.e. the new data frame should look like this:

| fips | year | pollutant | nonattainment | nonattainment_pm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72137 | 1992 | Sulfur Dioxide (1971) |  | 1 |
| 72137 | 1992 | PM-2.5 (1997) | P | 1 |
| 72137 | 1992 | 8-Hour Ozone (2015) | W | 1 |
| 72137 | 1992 | 'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)' |  | 1 |
| 72137 | 1993 | Sulfur Dioxide (1971) |  |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | PM-2.5 (1997) |  |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | 8-Hour Ozone (2015) | W |  |
| 72137 | 1993 | 'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)' |  |  |

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked this post: [Creating a new column based on if-elif-else condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21702342/10452700)? Kindly, Please Google or check previous similar questions to avoid duplication. You didn't include what you have tried and which error you have faced so far!!

Comment: Obviously I looked at that answer and also googled my problem, if I had found a suitable solution I wouldn't have asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
pollutant_l = ['PM-2.5 (1997)', 'PM-2.5 (2006)', 'PM-10 (1987)', 'PM-2.5 (2012)']

df['nonattainment_pm'] = np.where((df['pollutant'].isin(pollutant_l)) & (df['nonattainment'].isin(['P', 'W'])), 1, 0)
df['nonattainment_pm'] = df.groupby(['fips', 'year'])['nonattainment_pm'].transform('max')
```

output:

```
    fips  year                  pollutant nonattainment  nonattainment_pm
0  72137  1992      Sulfur Dioxide (1971)           NaN                 1
1  72137  1992              PM-2.5 (1997)             P                 1
2  72137  1992        8-Hour Ozone (2015)             W                 1
3  72137  1992  'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)'           NaN                 1
4  72137  1993      Sulfur Dioxide (1971)           NaN                 0
5  72137  1993              PM-2.5 (1997)           NaN                 0
6  72137  1993        8-Hour Ozone (2015)             W                 0
7  72137  1993  'Nitrogen Dioxide (1971)'           NaN                 0
```